# Letting $z$ vary and seeing the effect on $\sqrt {1 - z^2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $\sqrt{1-z^2}=1$ for $z=0$. Show that as $z$ varies from $0 \to p>1$ along the real axis, $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ varies from $1 \to -i\sqrt{1-z^2}$.

Should $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ not just vary from $1 \to \sqrt{1-p^2}?$ I don't understand where the $-i$ came from. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hem, what is $\sqrt{1-2^2}$ ?

Comment: It is z^2,not 2^2.

Comment: Are you kidding ? $z$ varies.

Comment: Why. What is the problem

Comment: Yes so if z varies from 0 to p, why does sqrt(1-z^2) vary from 1 to -i*sqrt(1-p^2)

Comment: What is $\sqrt{1-2^2}$, again ?

Comment: What Yves is trying to say is that $1 - 2^2 < 0$ and is thus negative. So you will get $\sqrt {negative}$ which is why $-i$ is there; $-i$ in particular (instead of $i$) because $\sqrt {1 - 2^2} = -\sqrt {2^2 - 1}$

Comment: It is wrong to say that $\sqrt{-x}=-\sqrt{-x}$, but now you know where $i$ was coming from.

Comment: @GeorgeN.Missailidis It is good that you posted your last comment because it clearly enunciates your misconception about "square roots" of complex numbers (unfortunately repeated in the answer below). For your interest, there is no reason to declare that $\sqrt{-3}$ is $i\sqrt3$ rather than $-i\sqrt3$, which is why it is preferable to avoid altogether the notation $\sqrt{z}$ when $z$ is not a nonnegative real number...

Comment: OP: Why accept a wrong answer? To test the system?

Answer (score 1):

There are several anomalies in the problem statement, here is a complete discussion.

When $p$ varies from $0$ to $p>1$, there are two regimes:

- from $0$ to $1$, $1-z^2\ge0$ and $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ is a real, non-negative.
- after $1$, $1-z^2\le0$ and we must switch to the complex numbers. The complex square root has two branches to choose from, $\pm i\sqrt{z^2-1}$ (where the square root applies to a real number, hence is the ordinary square root).

Unexpectedly, the author seems to have chosen the minus sign, which is unusual. And the expression $-i\sqrt{1-z^2}$ is wrong, the terms inside the square root must be swapped.

The complete variation scheme is

$$1\to0\to-i\sqrt{p^2-1}.$$

---

The problem statement raises another incoherence.

In the reals, the *principal* square root is a positive number, and we do have $\sqrt1=1$.

In the complex we also have a *principal* square root, such that $i:=\sqrt{-1}$.

So mixing $\sqrt1=1$ with $\sqrt{-1}=-i$ is illogical.